# Is it possible to show a specific row I want in this situation?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2014

This is the scenario so far. I am supposed to show the 4th highest (only the 4th, not the top 4) paid people in the company. However I don't want to use sub-queries. That's the problem. I can't seem to find a way to show only the 4th.

This is the current code I have

```
SELECT TOP 5 E1.BusinessEntityID, SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) AS Pay
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E1
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E2
ON E1.BusinessEntityID=E2.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY E1.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) DESC
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: why you dont want use subquery? Is like you say I dont want use db. What is your rdbms?

Comment: Actually it's a challenge at our college that no one seems to be able to answer.
Using AdventureWorks 2014 btw

Comment: You can find AdventureWorks in different RBDMS, I mean are you using SqlServer, Postgres, MySQL ... and what version ??

Comment: SQL Server Development Edition

Comment: what should be returned if there are multiple rows with the 4th highest salary?

Comment: Well in this case there are no equal results in the top 5. However I know of a function called WITH TIES, that shows all "same place" result. Like If you have 2 people in 3rd place. It would show both if you use it. But in this scenario, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OFFSET/FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) will do this easily:

```
SELECT TOP 5 E1.BusinessEntityID, SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) AS Pay
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E1
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E2
   ON E1.BusinessEntityID=E2.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY E1.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) DESC
OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Omg, thank you very much... I have been googling for hours trying to find a way. Found LAST_VALUE and other stuff, but none of them worked. You have no idea how thankful I am.

Comment: I think no need for top 5

Comment: @Paparazzi yeah, I just copy/pasted what he already had and added offset/fetch without paying too much attention to the rest. At least TOP 5 doesn't hurt in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You also can do this using row number

```
with cte
as
(
SELECT TOP 5 E1.BusinessEntityID, SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) AS Pay,row_number() over (ORDER BY SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) DESC) as rn
FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E1
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory AS E2
ON E1.BusinessEntityID=E2.BusinessEntityID
GROUP BY E1.BusinessEntityID
ORDER BY SUM(E2.PayFrequency*E2.Rate) DESC
)
select * from cte where rn=4
```

Comment: Thank you very much... You just gave me new ways to play around in SQL with that. :D

Comment: This may be what the class challenge was really after, but fwiw I'd count CTE's as another kind of sub query.